# Chess Queen check diagonal attack problem Python

Tags: python

everyone!
I have a problem with check attack of chess Queens.
I have an input with number which says me how many pairs of coordinates we will have and another input with two numbers of those coordinates.
For example input 3 ---> (2, 3), (7, 8), (5, 4)
In these coordinates we place a Queen.
I have a code like this and the problem for me is that check of diagonals attacks works correctly only when in range of 1.
I need ur help or advice.

```
arr = [
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]


# for good vision
def show_arr(arr):
    for row in arr:
        print(''.join([f'{el:^4}' for el in row]))


#  placing our Queens by coordinates
def get_figure(arr, coords_list):
    for cord in coords_list:
        for ir, row in enumerate(range(8), start=1):
            for ic, col in enumerate(range(8), start=1):
                if ir == cord[0] and ic == cord[1]:
                    arr[row][col] = 'Q'
    return arr

# Check for attack
def check(arr):
    s = 1
    for ir, row in enumerate(range(8), start=1):
        for ic, col in enumerate(range(8), start=1):
            if arr[row][col] == 'Q':
                if arr[row-1][col+1]:
                    return 'YES'
                elif arr[row-1][col-1]:
                    return 'YES'
                elif arr[row+1][col-1]:
                    return 'YES'
                elif arr[row+1][col+1]:
                    return 'YES'
    else:
        return 'NO'

            

if __name__ == '__main__':

    coords_list = [[1, 1], [5, 5], [2, 4], [7, 7]]
    show_arr(get_figure(arr, coords_list))

    print(check(get_figure(arr, coords_list)))
```

Comment: To fix: don't `return 'NO'` in loops, return it only after loops, at the end of the function (remove `else:`, put only 4 spaces before `return 'NO'`). Right now first NO returns = exits the function, so the rest of the loop is not run

Comment: Done. still not working

Comment: Shouldn't function check return "YES" or "NO" based upon whether it attacks a particular square.  I don't understand why it should return "YES" or "NO" for the entire board.